# How can I render a transparent gradient with RMagick?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, image-manipulation, imagemagick, rmagick

Want to use RMagick to create a PNG image of a gradient that goes from rgba(0,0,0,0.3) to rgba(0,0,0,0.7). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it cannot be done. If you take a look at c code in [here](http://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/blob/master/ext/RMagick/rmfill.c#L303) you will see that opacity is automatically set to OpaqueOpacity. Furthermore, if you take a look at how fills are implemented, they only write the image.

On the other hand, it could be done at a lower level. If the opacity is always the same, you can use an ImageList and then flatten it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to generate a transparent gradient image from within RMagick by using the
[Gradient Built-in Format](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/imusage.html#builtin_formats) and
`Image.read()`:

```
require 'RMagick'

img = Magick::Image.read("gradient:rgba(0,0,0,0.3)-rgba(0,0,0,0.7)") do
    self.size = "100x100"
end
img.first.write("out.png")
```

This is the same as running the following in the command line:

```
$ convert -size 100x100 'gradient:rgba(0,0,0,0.3)-rgba(0,0,0,0.7)' out.png
```